# R bin timestamps occuring between two timestamps

Tags: r, timestamp

I have a dataframe consisting of:

- two columns with start and end timestamps (POSIXct class) of various 
  projects
- another timestamp (POSIXct class) column showing events which
  occured within the start and end timeframe
- a project id column
  Projects have multiple events naturally.

  ```
  Projid  Event                     BEGIN_DT            END_DT              
  1       04/12/2013 09:00:00      04/12/2013 08:12:00 04/14/2013 20:14:00
  1       04/13/2013 15:16:24      04/12/2013 08:12:00 04/14/2013 20:14:00
  2       06/06/2012 18:00:00      06/06/2012 13:54:32 08/06/2012 23:59:43
  2       06/07/2012 22:54:32      06/06/2012 13:54:32 08/06/2012 23:59:43
  ```

I would like to add a field showing for each event the 60 min time bucket it belongs to (as in first hour or second hour or n-th hour of the project etc...). How could this be done?

Comment: Are you looking for the hour of the event? Can you provide the expected output for the example you've given?

Comment: No, i do not need the hour of the event, but the nth 60 minute segment (starting from project begin time) to which it belongs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following using a `floor` on the `difftime` in hours:

```
# Your sample data
df <- structure(list(
    Projid = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
    Event = structure(c(1365721200, 1365830184, 1338969600, 1339073672), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
    BEGIN_DT = structure(c(1365718320, 1365718320, 1338954872, 1338954872), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
    END_DT = structure(c(1365934440, 1365934440, 1344261583, 1344261583), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")),
    .Names = c("Projid", "Event", "BEGIN_DT", "END_DT"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame");

# Add hour bin
df$hourBin <- floor(difftime(df$Event, df$BEGIN_DT, unit = "hours")) + 1;
df;
#Projid               Event            BEGIN_DT              END_DT  hourBin
#1      1 2013-04-12 09:00:00 2013-04-12 08:12:00 2013-04-14 20:14:00  1 hours
#2      1 2013-04-13 15:16:24 2013-04-12 08:12:00 2013-04-14 20:14:00 32 hours
#3      2 2012-06-06 18:00:00 2012-06-06 13:54:32 2012-08-06 23:59:43  5 hours
#4      2 2012-06-07 22:54:32 2012-06-06 13:54:32 2012-08-06 23:59:43 34 hours
```